# Redirect root/dir to root/new/dir with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directadmin

I have a directadmin host and domain, and I create directories in host and in the every directory is one index.html with url like this:

> example.com/sdeds

Later, I installed a WordPress on the hosts and folded new directories like this:

> example.com/2018/asdfa

But my old directories are in the root and very sloppy. I want create new directory and move them but don't miss the address that customers have, since addresses are provided as qr code to the customer. Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect everything from root, excluding the `/2018/asdfa` directory (that contains WordPress), into a new subdirectory then you can do something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^2018/asdfa /newdirectory%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

> **UPDATE:** What if I have more than one directory to excluding? like: 2018, 2019, 2020

If it's just directories like you mention, then it would be easiest to just use *alternation* in the regex. For example:

```
RewriteRule !^20(18|19|20)/asdfa /newdirectory%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

The `(18|19|20)` subpattern matches either `18`, `19` or `20`.

If you wanted to match anything that looks-like a "recent" year then you can use a more generalized pattern. For example:

```
RewriteRule !^20[12]\d/asdfa /newdirectory%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

`20[12]\d` matches the strings (ie. directories) `2010` to `2029` (inclusive). `[12]` is a character class that matches either `1` or `2`. And `\d` is a shorthand character class that matches any digit 0-9 (the same as `[0-9]`).

Comment: What if I have more than one directory to excluding? like: 2018, 2019, 2020

Comment: You can use regex _alternation_ for those few directories. I've updated my answer.